# Jensen Inequality, a question about the proof and the statement

Tags: probability, inequality, proof-verification, jensen-inequality

I am not too sure about the following proof of the Jensen Inequality, in fact, I also doubt about the proposition.

[image]

The first thing is that $f:C \to R$ so, How does they know that $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_ix_i \in C$, in order to apply $f$ to this vector. Later, in the proof they apply $f$ to $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} \lambda_ix_i/(1 - \lambda_m)$, again, how does they know that this belongs to $C$.

Comment: By the name it seems that $C$ stands for a convex set, so $\sum\limits_{I=1}^mλ_ix_i,\ \sum\limits_{I=1}^{m-1}\frac{λ_ix_i}{1-λ_m}\in C$.

Comment: Don't use images in this way, it makes it impossible for future users to find your question through search. Instead, take the time to transcribe your question.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!! @TonyS.F.

Comment: @Ale.B And this definition implies that for any $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in C$, $λ_1,\cdots,λ_n\geqslant0$, if $\sum λ_i=1$ then $\sum λ_ix_i\in C$.

Comment: [Related answer on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) about the issue that Tony S.F. raised.

Comment: I am not seeing this! Can you prove it?

Comment: If not, give me some hint! @Alex Francisco

Comment: @Ale.B Induction on $n$ works.

Comment: I swear I have already tried this, by then i didnt manage to do it. Now i get it! Thanks and sorry for the stupid question

Answer (score 0):

A full translation from spanish would likely be welcomed in an english forum, but I guess it's okay. The proof checks out as far as I reviewed it, though as you point out it could have delved into more detail.

To answer: "How does they know that $∑_m^i=1λ_i x_i∈C$, in order to apply f to this vector. ": From the list of hypothesis (or from the description of entities) $C$ is convex, hence if

$$ x_1, x_2 \in C, \lambda_1,\lambda_2 \geq0, \lambda_1+\lambda_2=1 \Rightarrow \lambda_1x_1+\lambda_2 x_2 \in C $$

Think that the line connecting these two points is contained in C. Then this can be generalized for the pondered sum of $n$ points.

To answer why $ ∑^{m−1}_{i=1}λ_ix_i/(1−λ_m) \in C$, just note that the coefficient of each $x_i$ is positive yet smaller than unity.

Assuming $1 >\lambda_m > 0$, then:

$$ 1 > (1-\lambda_m) > 0  $$

Then for each $1>\lambda_i\geq0$

Assume (for contradiction) that:

$$
\frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_m} \geq 1
$$
Then:
$$
\lambda_i \geq 1-\lambda_m \Rightarrow \lambda_i +\lambda_m \geq 1
$$

Which either means that all other $\lambda_k$ are zero, thus amking the situation fall into the inductive step, or a contradiction of the hypothesis that $\sum \lambda_i =1$.